# centered zoom in custom view - calculating canvas coordinates

Tags: android, view, zooming

I am working on my first "real" Android application, a graphical workflow editor. The drawing is done in a custom class, that is a subclass of View.At the moment my elements are rectangles, which are drawn on a canvas. To detect actions on elements I compare the coordinates and check for elements on the touch location.

To implement a zoom gesture I tried http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html

With the 4 argument canvas.scale(...) function the centered zooming works well, but I lose the ability to calculate the canvas coordinates using the offset with mPosX and mPosY to detect if the touch after a zoom is on an element.

I tried to change the example in the blogpost above to center the canvas on the zoom gesture with:

```
canvas.save();
canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);
canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, mScalePivotX, mScalePivotY);
//drawing ....
canvas.restore();
```

I did not find any examples on how this could be done without losing the reference offset to calculate the coordinates. Is there an easy workaround? I tried to calculate the offset with the gesture center and the scaling factor, but failed :/

I have seen that other examples which use an ImageView often use a Matrix to transform the image. Could this be done with a custom View and a Canvas? If yes, how can I get the x and y offset to check the coordinates?

Also, if my ideas are completely wrong, I would be very happy to see some examples on how this is done properly.

Thx! ;)

Comment: hi, i am facing the issue of centering the zoom. currently when i zoom in it goes to point (0,0) and i am using this method canvas.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);. how are you calculating the ScalePivotX and scalePivotY? 

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the following code will help you to calculate coordinates with the gesture center and the scaling factor. I use this method in my class representing opengl-sprite.

```
void zoom(float scale, PointF midPoint) {
    if (zoomFactor == MAX_ZOOM_FACTOR && scale > 1) return;
    if (zoomFactor == MIN_ZOOM_FACTOR && scale < 1) return;

    zoomFactor *= scale;
    x = (x - midPoint.x) * scale + midPoint.x;
    y = (y - height + midPoint.y) * scale + height - midPoint.y;
    if (zoomFactor >= MAX_ZOOM_FACTOR) {
        zoomFactor = MAX_ZOOM_FACTOR;
    } else if (zoomFactor < MIN_ZOOM_FACTOR) {
        zoomFactor = MIN_ZOOM_FACTOR;
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
    }
}
```

X and Y coordinates are processed in different ways, because of distinction between directions of opengl coordinate system (right and up) and midPoint's coordinate system (right and down). midPoint is taken from `MotionEvent`s coordinates.

All other operations are understandable, i think.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: sorry, i completely forgot about this question. i came up with something very similar in the end, but don't have the code anymore to update my question with my solution. thx